# Getting Elasticsearch response

Tags: json, go, elasticsearch, eof

I am using gin framework to built an Api to get data from Elastic.
Issue is that when I run the application, I get response successfully in the first request but after that in any subsequent request I am getting error:

```
Error parsing the response body: EOF
```

Elastic configuration:

```
var cfg = elasticsearch.Config{
    Password:  GetConnectConfig().esPassword,
    Username:  GetConnectConfig().esUserName,
    Addresses: GetConnectConfig().esHost,
    Logger: &estransport.ColorLogger{
        Output:             os.Stdout,
    }
```

My request handler function looks like:

```
func Search() gin.HandlerFunc {

    client, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("elastic configuration failed %s", err)
    }

    res, err := client.Search(
        client.Search.WithIndex(Index_Name),
        client.Search.WithSize(10),
        client.Search.WithPretty(),
        )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("elastic failed to respond %s", err)
    }

    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        r := map[string]interface{}{}
        if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&r); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": err})
            log.Fatalf("Error parsing the response body: %s", err)            // Error 
        } else {
            for _, hit := range r["hits"].(map[string]interface{})["hits"].([]interface{}) {
                log.Printf(" * ID=%s, %s", hit.(map[string]interface{})["_id"], hit.(map[string]interface{})["_source"])
            }
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "success")
        }
    }
}
```

As I told, I am able to get the response only in the very first request each time I run the application.
I am not sure what is the cause of error here.

I also tried with closing the response body after search by adding:

```
defer res.Body.Close()
```

but now I am getting following error:

```
Error parsing the response body: http2: response body closed
```

Comment: i guess your `defer res.Body.Close()` should be inside the func(c *gin.Context){} as your first statement, your handler is returning a function which will execute at a later time you cannot close body inside your handler.. or move your search initialization inside the func and do a close inside there

Comment: it is better to initialize your elastic search client in your main.go or in your app bootsrap and pass it as a dependency to your handler

Comment: I figured out the issue, It was coming from the same place as you pointed. After initializing the client in main function and executing elastic search query inside func(c *gin.Context){}, I am able to get the results.
Thank you for your quick reply. Can you please post the solution here? or if you want I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defer res.Body.Close()` should be inside the func(c *gin.Context){} yo. can move your search initialization inside the func and do a close inside there something like and client can be injected as a dependency here.

```
 return func(c *gin.Context) {
          res, err := client.Search(
           client.Search.WithIndex(Index_Name),
           client.Search.WithSize(10),
           client.Search.WithPretty(),
          )
          defer res.Body.Close()
   }
}
```